# Content Migration for a Specific Folder

Tags: python, plone

I have a script, migrating Image to a custom type, for my Plone instance. Its partial code sample looks like this:

```
class ImagesToPhotosMigrator(InplaceATItemMigrator):
    src_portal_type = 'Image'
    src_meta_type = 'ATBlob'
    dst_portal_type = 'Photo'
    dst_meta_type = 'Photo'

    def last_migrate_reindex(self):
        self.new.reindexObject(idxs=['object_provides', 'portal_type',
            'Type', 'UID'])

    fields_map = {
    }

def getImagesToPhotosMigrationWalker(self):
    return getMigrationWalker(self, migrator=ImagesToPhotosMigrator)

def migrateImages(self):
    walker = getImagesToPhotosMigrationWalker(self)
    walker.go()
    return walker.getOutput()
```

The script works, but I want the migration only happens in a specific folder, say `/my-folder`, what to add in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have specified that you refer to [Products.contentmigration](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.contentmigration), cause it's not implicit in the words "content migration" (lately there are more kind of migrations than lines of code). Anyway, here your solution (`CustomQueryWalker` is the key):

```
from Products.contentmigration.walker import CustomQueryWalker

def getImagesToPhotosMigrationWalker(self, query):
    return CustomQueryWalker(self, ImagesToPhotosMigrator, query)

def migrateImages(self):
    walker = getImagesToPhotosMigrationWalker(self, {'path' : '/youfolder'})
    walker.go()
    return walker.getOutput()
```

Note that the query parameter is a catalog query, therefore you can specify the path, the portal_type or any index in your catalog.

Comment: Yes, I should have specified it's Products.contentmigration used.